# Display Auto Generated Youtube Thumbnails with 'Video Embed Field' Module in Views

Tags: views, media, files, javascript

I added some videos to my site and I'm using views to display them. I followed a [tutorial](http://www.waldbeek.com/blog/drupal-flash-video-lightbox-tutorial) and i used the **rewrite the output** option of the view with allowed **replacement patterns** to display videos in lightbox in this way.

```
<a href="[field_video-video-url]" rel="lightvideo"><img src="[field_vthumb]" 
height="120" width="180"></a>
```

Here when i clicked on the a image, the video will played in the lightbox and that was great.
In the above link added a custom the image field as thumbnail but that doesn't work well, because when i add more than one video all will have the same thumbnail.

But then i also came to know, that the **Video Embed Module** when used to add videos, auto generates the thumbails of the added youtube videos in a public directory. So again i worked on the replacement patterns and got the raw thumbnail field generated by the Video Embed Module.

Again i rewrote the output with the raw thumbnail as image

```
 <a href="[field_video-video-url]" rel="lightvideo"><img src="[field_video-thumbnail_path]" 
 height="120" width="180"></a>
```

But the thumbnail image is broken and the image path is shown as 
`public://video_embed_field_thumbnails/youtube/RQieoqCLWDo.jpg` which i guess is not recognized by drupal.

So my point here is, Is there a way to access the **raw thumbnail** in the **rewrite patterns** so that every youtube video gets its own thumbnail without manually adding image as thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

I only use the video embed field in views and have set the formatter to colorbox. I get the auto-generated thumbnails by default and on click of it, the video opens in a colorbox. You don't need to do anything else then this.